# Slow Cheetah stopped working in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio-2013, slowcheetah

Suddenly, and inexplicably, Slow Cheetah has stopped working inside Visual Studio 2013.  By "stopped working" I mean:

1. The context menus no longer appear (ie Preview Transform, Add
   Transform)
2. Config file transforms no longer occur when the project is built.

By "suddenly" I mean yesterday it was working, and today it is not.  I'm not aware of what changed on my computer that would cause Slow Cheetah to break

This happened for every solution on my machine (new or old).  The problem seems to reside in Visual Studio itself.

There are many SO answers to this question, but all of them boil down to these 3 suggestions, which I tried:

1. Un-install and re-install the Slow Cheetah Nuget package using the Visual Studio library package manager.
2. Look in the *.csproj file and verify that the "PropertyGroup" section is above the "Import Project" element.
3. Delete %APPDATA%..\Local\Microsoft\MSBuild\SlowCheetah and rebuild.

Is there any way to debug this issue?  Nothing appears in the build output window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was to go to this page and install the Slow Cheetah Visual Studio extension:

[Slow Cheetah Extension](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/69023d00-a4f9-4a34-a6cd-7e854ba318b5/view/Reviews/5)

Odd, as Slow Cheetah worked on my machine for years installing it from the NuGet package; I never installed this extension.

Comment: Latest link is here for VS 2013 extension. Microsoft's latest release doesn't support VS 2013.
https://github.com/sayedihashimi/slow-cheetah/releases/tag/v2.5.48